# GridView to load faster or synchronously

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, baseadapter

I have created a GridView to load like a gallery/ thumbnail list of Images

All though the overall result is good, the time it takes to load and call the repetitive getView  can take a while on 100+ images.

Any thought on how do get the images to load faster

Of can you somehow cause an Adapter  that extends BaseAdapter to load multiple getViews at once say 12 , as there are 12 images on the screen at any time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the `getView` only gets called for the amount of images currently visable on the screen so it is not calling getView 100+ times, after the adapter loads the appropriate number of images to the adapter getView only gets called when you start scrolling. If you want faster loading create a smaller version of your image (thumbnail) so it does not load the full image every time

you should read this article about loading images

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thanks the Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently Lesson, is the on I am already current using. Loading just 15 images (which as you said) is what is on screen   05-06 16:06:01.807 to 05-06 16:06:16.047 a 15 second process. even when scrolling it moves a little then stops, while loading then shows all new images.  That is what I'm trying to correct, where it can show one image at a time.  rather than appear to do nothing, and then show 15 images at once.

Comment: run your async task using `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` this will allow multiple tasks to run at the same time. also it sounds like you are using the full res image, that is going to take a while which is why I recommend creating a thumbnail for the image